# How can I parse this proprietary text file into CSV with maybe regex and/or Python?

Tags: python, csv, parsing, text

I have been given a config file from an old proprietary system that I want to parse into a CSV so I can import it into a SharePoint List or an Excel file, and access it with either Power BI or Power Apps. (the old system may be something called ptube, but I'm not certain.)

Part of the file is below. I am told that all that is really needed to be exported are the first entry of each item (in this excerpt that would be 'Zone1','Blower100', and 'TU110') and the field 'cycles' - all other data can be discarded. Some of 'items' do not have a 'cycles' field - those can be entirely ignored. Lines starting with `//` are apparently comments and can be ignored.

So, for the file below, we would want:

```
Blower100, 2693452
TU110, 577754
```

output to a text or Excel file.
(note that the first entry, 'Zone1' is skipped because there is no 'cycles' field for that item.)

The file contains 48K lines, only the first three items are in the file below. They want to be able to reload this file on a regular basis, so I need some sort of script that can be run regularly to do this.

My programming background is mostly in Java and SQL, and I could probably do this with Java, but I have limited tools available to me at this new job and no access to Java. My job here is to develop Power Apps and Power BI reports, and Power Automate scripts, all of which I am very familiar with, but I don't know how I could convert this file using only those tools.

I have whatever is available within Windows 10 (PowerShell included, but not cmd), and the software I have listed below. The company laptop given to me is very 'locked down' and I cannot install additional software, though I can request that IT install software if I can justify it (and it is cheap or free).

Software available to me is:

- Power Platform suite (Power Apps, Power BI, Power Automate)
- I can create SharePoint Lists
- All Office 365 apps like Excel
- SQL, and access to a SQL Server, and SSMS
- Visual Studio 2022 with Python (which I do not know, but would like
  to learn)
- PowerShell (but NOT CMD)

I know this is a lot to ask, but if anybody can help me, or point me to a solution, I would appreciate it!

Griffin

```
// Server Version: 7.2.5.1 [May 28 2020 05:59:27]
// ESP Version: 7.02.05.01 12:00:00 [ 09/07/22 ]
// Configuration saved: Fri Nov 17 13:46:52
Zone1 {
  aliasName= "";
  unitDescriptor= "";
  retries= 0;
  totalRetries= 0;
  resetRetriesTm= 0;
  successMoves= 0;
  recvrySet= ;
  recovery= Station220;
  useZeroLevel= 0;
  outsideAir= 0;
  commLine= 255;
  fullTime= 0;
  speed= 20;
  // Equipment level configuration
  port 0 : Blower100;
}

Blower100 {
  aliasName= "";
  unitDescriptor= "Core Penthouse";
  retries= 0;
  totalRetries= 0;
  resetRetriesTm= 1686697175;
  successMoves= 0;
  isXpBlower= 0;
  commLine= Line410;
  strapAdd= 100;
  pvTime= 3;
  idleTime= 10;
  purgeTime= 15;
  mechanics= 0;
  cycles= 2693452;
  offOn= 0;
  starts= 2123;
  startTm= 1700243194;
  resetStart= 1658292126;
  hours= 38173707;
  resetHrs= 1658292122;
  resetCycleTm= 1658292118;
  revision= "03.00.00.007";
  csum= " ";
  promDate= "11/25/13";
  program= "TUBLOWER.BN3";
  downloading= 0;
  bootloadertype= 1;
  // Equipment level configuration
  port 0 : TU110;
  up : Zone1;
}

TU110 {
  aliasName= "";
  unitDescriptor= "Core Penthouse.  Above platform";
  retries= 3;
  totalRetries= 1;
  resetRetriesTm= 1686697188;
  successMoves= 0;
  revision= "03.00.00.007";
  csum= " ";
  promDate= "11/25/13";
  restrictTrnarnd= 0;
  commLine= Line412;
  strapAdd= 110;
  upStreamPort= 0;
  ports= 4;
  mechanics= 0;
  cycles= 577754;
  resetCycleTm= 1634092201;
  costs[0]= 1;
  costs[1]= 1;
  costs[2]= 1;
  costs[3]= 1;
  costs[4]= 1;
  costs[5]= 1;
  samples[0]= 10;
  samples[1]= 0;
  samples[2]= 0;
  samples[3]= 0;
  samples[4]= 0;
  samples[5]= 0;
  program= "TUBLOWER.BN3";
  downloading= 0;
  bootloadertype= 1;
  // Equipment level configuration
  port 0 : TU101;
  port 1 : ByPass971;
  port 2 : IZ930;
  port 3 : IZ931;
  up : Blower100;
}
```

Comment: learn to use regex

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach

1. Scan through the lines in the input file
2. If the line ends with a open curly bracket `{`, record the text before that
3. If the line contains 'cycles=' then record the value after the equal sign
4. In the end, data is collected in the `rows` variable and write out to a file

```py
import csv

rows = []
col0 = ""
col1 = ""

with open("in.txt") as stream:
    for line in stream:
        line = line.strip()
        if line.endswith("{"):
            col0 = line.split()[0]
        elif "cycles" in line and "=" in line:
            col1 = line.removesuffix(";").split("=", 1)[-1]
            rows.append([col0, col1])

with open("out.csv", "w") as stream:
    writer = csv.writer(stream)
    writer.writerows(rows)
```